# Why does when loss decease accuracy deceases as well, tensor-flow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to train a classification model, where the loss is decreasing but the accuracy decreases as well, which does not make sense to me. I thought I was calculating accuracy wrong but that doesn't seem to be the case. Shouldn't as loss decrease, accuracy increase be the case? or there is no correlation between loss and accuracy at all?

```
import numpy as np
import random
import numpy.core.multiarray
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob
from get_data import next_batch, rawData
test, train, result_dict = rawData()

# optimization varibles
learning_rate = 1e-3 # 0.05
epochs = 100 # 100
batch_size = 64 # 50
dropout = 0.9

# Network Parameters
n_input = 6000 # 784
n_hidden1 = 5000 # 512
n_hidden2 = 4500 # 32*12 # 256
n_hidden3 = 500 
n_output = 4 # 10

# declare the training data placeholders
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_output])
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

# Weights 
weights = {
    'w1': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_input, n_hidden1], stddev=0.1)),
    'w2': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden1, n_hidden2], stddev=0.1)),
    # 'w3': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden2, n_hidden3], stddev=0.1)),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden2, n_output], stddev=0.1)),
}

# Biases
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_hidden1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_hidden2])),
    # 'b3': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_hidden3])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_output]))
}

# Layers
layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(X, weights['w1']), biases['b1']))
layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['w2']), biases['b2']))
# layer_3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['w3']), biases['b3']))
layer_drop = tf.nn.dropout(layer_2, keep_prob)
output_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']

# Gradient 
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(
        labels=Y, logits=output_layer
        ))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)

# change that into tf.nn.softmax insta of argmax
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(output_layer, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)


for i in range(epochs): 
    # batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
    mapIndexPosition = list(zip(train["data"], train["labels"]))
    random.shuffle(mapIndexPosition)
    r_data, r_labels = zip(*mapIndexPosition)

    batchs = next_batch(batch_size, r_data, r_labels, shuffle=False)

    # print("---------------- i: ", i)

    for batch in batchs:

        batch_x, batch_y = batch

        feed_dict ={X: batch_x, Y:batch_y, keep_prob: dropout}

        _, loss = sess.run([train_step, cross_entropy], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict=feed_dict)


    if i % 10 == 0:
        print(
            "Iteration",
            str(i),
            "\t| Loss =",
            str(loss),
            "\t| Accuracy =",
            str(acc)
            )
# test_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: mnist.test.images, Y: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0})
test_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: test["data"], Y: test["labels"], keep_prob: 1.0})
print("\nAccuracy on test set:", test_accuracy)
```

Processing Data file:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob
# from data_structure import DataStructure

class GetData:

    bulk_data = None
    bulk_labels = None
    result = None
    img_data = None
    img_label = None
    result_dict = {'data': [], 'labels': []}

    def __init__(self, bulk_data, bulk_labels):
        # print("get_data works?")
        self.bulk_data = bulk_data
        self.bulk_labels = bulk_labels


        # Push the object in the array for the model class to use

    def structureData(self):
        # Object Structure in way that will have: Data and (correct) Label 
        # Make an object of whatever data came to be.
        self.result = []
        self.img_data = []
        self.img_label = []
        i = 0
        while(i < (len(self.bulk_data) and len(self.bulk_labels))):

            image = cv2.imread(self.bulk_data[i])

            scaled_image = cv2.resize(image, (64, 64))

            scaled_image = np.array(scaled_image).flatten()

            self.img_data.append(scaled_image)
            self.img_label.append(self.bulk_labels[i])

            self.result_dict["data"].append(scaled_image)
            self.result_dict["labels"].append(self.bulk_labels[i])

            i += 1

        return self.result

    def get_images(self):
        return self.img_data

    def get_label(self):
        return self.img_label

    def get_dict(self):
        return self.result_dict

    def get_raw_data(self):

        i = 0
        while(i < (len(self.bulk_data) and len(self.bulk_labels))):
            self.result_dict["data"].append(self.bulk_data[i])
            self.result_dict["labels"].append(self.bulk_labels[i])

            i += 1

        return self.result_dict

def next_batch(batch_size, data, labels, shuffle=False):
    data = np.asarray(data)
    labels = np.asarray(labels)

    # print(data.shape[0], labels.shape[0])
    # This has to change and iterate over the 
    assert data.shape[0] == labels.shape[0]
    if shuffle:
        indices = np.arange(data.shape[0])
        np.random.shuffle(indices)
    for start_idx in range(0, data.shape[0], batch_size):
        end_idx = min(start_idx + batch_size, data.shape[0])
        if shuffle:
            excerpt = indices[start_idx:end_idx]
        else:
            excerpt = slice(start_idx, end_idx)
        yield data[excerpt], labels[excerpt]


def rawData():
    test_data = {"data": [],"labels":[] }
    train_data = {"data": [], "labels": []}

    relationship_frame = pd.read_csv('relationships.csv')
    rawdata = relationship_frame.iloc[:,0].tolist()
    labels = relationship_frame.iloc[:,2].tolist()
    hot_encoding_labels = pd.get_dummies(labels)

    print(relationship_frame['Concentration'].value_counts())


    rawdata_temp = []

    for i in rawdata:
        raw_temp = eval(i)
        rawdata_temp.append(raw_temp)

    # print(len(rawdata_temp))
    data = GetData(rawdata_temp, hot_encoding_labels.values)

    result_dict = data.get_raw_data()

    # print(result_dict)
    test_ratio = round((len(result_dict["data"]) / 10) * 3)
    train_ratio = len(result_dict["data"]) - test_ratio

    test_data["data"] = result_dict["data"][:test_ratio]
    test_data["labels"] = result_dict["labels"][:test_ratio]

    # print(len(test_data["data"]), len(test_data["labels"]))

    for i in test_data["data"]:
        result_dict["data"].remove(i)
    for i in test_data["labels"]:
        result_dict["labels"].remove(i)

    train_data["data"] = result_dict["data"][:train_ratio]
    train_data["labels"] = result_dict["labels"][:train_ratio]

    # print(train_data["data"], len(train_data["labels"]))

    return test_data, train_data, result_dict
```

And the results that I'm getting are:

```
Iteration 0     | Loss = 11616709.0     | Accuracy = 0.29166666
Iteration 10    | Loss = 133036.08      | Accuracy = 0.20833333
Iteration 20    | Loss = 51588.387      | Accuracy = 0.41666666
Iteration 30    | Loss = 8822.799       | Accuracy = 0.25
Iteration 40    | Loss = 1.3812752      | Accuracy = 0.25
Iteration 50    | Loss = 1.3597528      | Accuracy = 0.41666666
Iteration 60    | Loss = 1.3821254      | Accuracy = 0.375
Iteration 70    | Loss = 1.3808714      | Accuracy = 0.375
Iteration 80    | Loss = 1.3909651      | Accuracy = 0.25
Iteration 90    | Loss = 1.3287157      | Accuracy = 0.41666666
```

See the loss decreases but so does the accuracy (Loss and Accuracy is per batch). Not sure what causes this. Am I doing something wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you. :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  Since you're working within the layers, you also have a chance to trace the results -- have you tried that, yet?

Comment: @Prune - I can post the code for processing data and even the data itself. Just that data is a .csv file and not sure If I can post that here. No, I haven't tried that yet. I'll try that right now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes, it appears you've done something wrong, in that your model appears to converge with what appears to be a substandard accuracy.  I'm not going to try to reverse-engineer the situation from partial code; I'll help you learn what to look for.

---

Loss and accuracy are correlated, but there is plenty of room for the two to head in different directions.

**Accuracy** is a discrete metric, a simple binary scoring for each input: if your model gets the right answer, it scores a point.  The batch accuracy is points/inputs.  It appears that your scores range from 5 to 10 correct out of 24.

**Loss** is an analogue metric of how far off your evaluations are.  This can be evaluated in many different ways; I don't know what loss function you're using.  I'll illustrate with a simple one.

You're trying to classify an input image as one of 10 digits, 0-9.  One simple loss function is the difference between your actual guess and a 100% certain prediction.  The model chooses the highest match proportion as the classification, but the loss function depends on the confidence.

Let's look at only digits 1, 2, 3 to keep the figures short.  Consider these cases in the evaluation of images arbitrarily labeled A-D.  Accuracy is simply whether or not the best guess is correct; loss is how far off the model has its confidence it the correct answer.

```
  image =>   A    B    C    D
confidence
      1     1.0  0.0  0.4  0.48
      2     0.0  1.0  0.3  0.51
      3     0.0  0.0  0.3  0.01
    label    1    1    1    1

    acc     1    0    1    0
    error   0.0  1.0  0.6  0.52
```

For each of the cases:

- A: NAILED IT: model is 100% confident and correct: 1 point (for accuracy), 0 loss
- B: TOTAL FAIL: model is 100% confident and wrong: 0 point, 1.0 loss
- C: BARELY GOT IT: model is 40% confident and correct: 1 point, 0.6 loss (1.0 - 0.4, confidence discrepancy)
- D: BARELY MISSED IT: model is 51% confident and wrong: 0 point, 0.52 loss (1.0 - 0.48)

Looking at C and D, you can see that the loss can be *more* for a correct guess than for an incorrect one, depending on the model's confusion about the image.

---

Obviously, your loss function is different; it's somehow scaled and uses a different function.  As with most models, the loss starts out deplorably high and drops quite nicely.  At iteration 40, you've achieved a very low loss: your loss function thinks that the model is doing an excellent job of evaluating the images.  However, there is some regular problem with the returned classifications: your accuracy is roughly 1/3.

You seem to have a test set of only 24 images; this will contribute to the problem, although it might do for your purposes.  I recommend that you trace the prediction confidences -- the vector result from the softmax transformation -- and compare that with the returned predictions.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.